# gcc: not linking files

Tags: c, gcc, linker

I have main.c, snmpy.c, snmpy.o, and a makefile. I running this on a Linux Server through command line. Here is what is all of them...

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "snmpy.h"

int main(void) {

   char* message = sayHello();

   printf("%s", message);

   return 0;
}
```

snmpy.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "snmpy.h"

char* sayHello(){

   char* hiya = "Hello!!\n";

   return hiya;

}
```

snmpy.h:

```
char* sayHello();
```

makefile:

```
# Compiler
CC = /usr/bin/gcc

# Name of program
PROG = snmpy

# The name of the object files
OBJS = snmpy.o main.o

# All the header and c files
SRCS = main.c snmpy.c
HDRS = snmpy.h

# Add -I to the dir the curl include files are in
CFLAGS = -c -g -std=c99 -Wall

# Build the executable file
$(PROG): $(OBJS)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJS) -o $(PROG)

# Seperately compile each .c file
main.o: main.c snmpy.h
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c main.c

snmpy.o: snmpy.c snmpy.h
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c snmpy.c

# Clean up crew
clean:
        rm -fv core* $(PROG) $(OBJS)

cleaner: clean
        rm -fv #* *~
```

When I compile it it gives me this error:

```
/usr/bin/gcc -c -g -std=c99 -Wall snmpy.o main.o -o snmpy
gcc: snmpy.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
gcc: main.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
```

Not sure what's going on whether there is something I'm not doing right, or if I didn't install something. I'm a noob at making make files. I haven't done them in a while.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Re:

```
/usr/bin/gcc -c -g -std=c99 -Wall snmpy.o main.o -o snmpy
```

The `-c` option in the command means **compile** (but don't link). The result of this will be `.o` (object) files.

Try the command without the `-c`,  it should link and create your `snmpy` executable.

Comment: @RobAveryIV Well, that's good news - what happened that it didn't work first?

Comment: lol, when I used vi I forgot to save. I went back into vi and removed the -c and saved it. Just a little bit of user error.

Answer (score 4):

By doing:-

```
# Build the executable file
$(PROG): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJS) -o $(PROG)
```

Because `CFLAGS` contains a `-c` you've said to use `-c` in the linking phase too.

You really want:-

```
$(PROG): $(OBJS)
```

Make should do the rest for you.

You could probably loose the `*.o` targets too.

Answer (score 3):

You need to lose the `-c` option to do full linking. The `-c` will just cause the source  files to be compiled into `*.o` files.

This is what the the `man gcc` call says about the `-c` option

> **-c**    Compile or assemble the source files, but do not link.  The linking
>    stage simply is not done.  The ultimate output is in the form of an
>    object file for each source file.
>
> By default, the object file name for a source file is made by
>     replacing the suffix .c, .i, .s, etc., with .o.
>
> Unrecognized input files, not requiring compilation or assembly,
>     are ignored.